# "npm install anything" only give me the same message of error

Tags: npm, sequelize.js, npm-install, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

i was trying to install sequelize with this command `npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli` and then the following message of error appear, and now when i try to install anything, the console always give me the same message:(in this case a try to install @babel/core)

```
root@DESKTOP-A350F45:/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1# npm install --save-dev @babel/core
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/@babel/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/@jest/transform/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/jest-resolve-dependencies/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/@babel/cli/node_modules/glob-parent/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/core/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/generator/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/extglob/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-changed-files/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-config/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-validate/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/node-notifier/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/read-pkg/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/koa-webpack/node_modules/@webpack-contrib/schema-utils/package.json'
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/helper-compilation-targets@7.13.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN request-promise-native@1.0.9 requires a peer of request@^2.34 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN request-promise-core@1.1.4 requires a peer of request@^2.34 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN proy_web1@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-06T18_27_03_328Z-debug.log
```

here i will put a portion of the complete log:

```
20159 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/@babel/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
20160 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20161 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
20161 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
20161 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
20161 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
20162 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/@jest/transform/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
20163 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20164 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
20164 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
20164 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
20164 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
20165 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
20166 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20167 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
20167 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
20167 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
20167 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
20168 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules/jest-resolve-dependencies/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
20169 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20170 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
20170 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
20170 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
20170 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
20171 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
20172 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20173 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
20173 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
20173 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
20173 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
20174 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
20175 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20176 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
20176 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
20176 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
20176 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
20177 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/@babel/cli/node_modules/glob-parent/package.json'
20178 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20179 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/core/package.json'
20180 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20181 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/generator/package.json'
20182 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20183 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/extglob/package.json'
20184 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20185 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/istanbul-lib-instrument/package.json'
20186 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20187 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-changed-files/package.json'
20188 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20189 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-config/package.json'
20190 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20191 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-validate/package.json'
20192 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20193 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/node-notifier/package.json'
20194 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20195 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/jest/node_modules/read-pkg/package.json'
20196 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20197 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1/node_modules/koa-webpack/node_modules/@webpack-contrib/schema-utils/package.json'
20198 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
20199 warn eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
20200 warn @babel/helper-compilation-targets@7.13.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
20201 warn tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
20202 warn request-promise-native@1.0.9 requires a peer of request@^2.34 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
20203 warn request-promise-core@1.1.4 requires a peer of request@^2.34 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
20204 warn proy_web1@1.0.0 No repository field.
20205 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
20205 verbose stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
20205 verbose stack     at isDepOptional (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:432:45)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:441:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20205 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
20206 verbose cwd /mnt/t/Users/Mr.Raul/koala/proyect_web/proy_web1
20207 verbose Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
20208 verbose argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "@babel/core"
20209 verbose node v12.18.3
20210 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20211 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
20212 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

pls any info that you need, only ask me, because i could have forgotten something :D